# How to shorten this jQuery onClick FadeOut to next Page code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout

I am trying to do a nice `FadeOut` if you click on a Link. The following Code is perfectly working.

My question is: **How can I shorten these functions?**  Demo: [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVPxoz)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newLocation = '';
    $('a, .fadeLink').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        newLocation = this.href;

        $('body').fadeOut(1000, changeLocation);
    });

    function changeLocation() {
       window.location = newLocation;
    }
});
```

Comment: Direktive 1337: Weiterleitung angeordnet!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425287/using-jquery-fadeout-for-page-transition

Comment: You can shorten the function any number of ways which are most likely based on personal preferences though. Maybe this question fits better on [**https://codereview.stackexchange.com**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: How short the code is matters less. I would personally remove the global variable. Make a named function instead of an anonymous one to refer to as the click event handler i.e: `$('a, .fadeLink').on('click', changePage});`  and pass the location as a parameter to the `changeLocation` function. Clean, Readable, Self-Explanatory and Testable Code > Short Code. That's just my opinion, hence I'm not posting it as an answer. If you want, you can also extrapolate the fade behavior so you can change fade to any other behavior with ease later and don't have it tightly coupled to changing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually looks quite good already. You could shorten it (not necessarily better) by taking an arrow function instead of the additional function, so you can closure the link:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a, .fadeLink').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     $('body').fadeOut(1000, () => window.location = this.href);
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot about this option!

Answer (score 0):

You can lose the `$(document).ready` function by placing the JavaScript code just before closing the `<body>` tag. Also, you don't have to define `newLocation` in the upper scope, you can pass it to the `changeLocation` function instead:

```
$('a, .fadeLink').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var location = this.href;

    $('body').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        changeLocation(location);
    });
});

function changeLocation(location) {
    window.location = location;
}
```

You could also get rid of the `changeLocation` function:

```
$('a, .fadeLink').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var location = this.href;

    $('body').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        window.location = location;
    });
});
```

In the end it's a matter of preference. Keep in mind that compacter code is not always better code.